# How to remove space between expression and period within a string? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Good Morning,

I've been trying to get rid of the space between the period and the number generated from sum(random_list) output [23739]. But can't seem to figure out how without turning the entire string to an f-string. I understand adding the comma will automatically insert a space, but can anyone let me know if there's an easier method? Thank you!

The picture below is my work;

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xsiF.png)

Comment: Can I ask what is so complicated in using `f-string`? and in using a comma?

Comment: I would have to add the entire sentence into a variable first, then type out the f string itself. Not to mention, also store the value of sum(random_list) into another variable to include it as well. We have moved passed f-strings 2 lessons ago and I can't help but feel I am simply overlooking things.

Comment: `print(f'The sum of... {sum(...)} .')` seems to be simple enough, no need to use variables.

Comment: Yeah simple, haha.

Comment: Either you can use `f-string` or you can give `sep=''` in your `print()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format` feature of string.

```
print("The sum of the elements in random list is {}.".format(sum(random_list)))
```

Comment: Do people still use *format()* ?

Comment: Yeah, `format` is useful when you want to realize left and right justification.

Comment: left/right justification is available in f-string formatting

Answer (score 1):

I think this f-string should work

```py
print(f"The sum of the elements in random list is {sum(random_list)}.")
```